# How to sort gridview with autogenerate column false?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview-sorting

I have a gridview with autogenerate column false.I want to sort the gridview on click on each the column header.My code works fine for autogenerate column true but i want it to be true.

My code:

```
Protected Sub grdWork_Sorting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewSortEventArgs) Handles grdPWork.Sorting

    If ViewState("SortDirection") = SortDirection.Ascending Then
        ViewState("SortDirection") = SortDirection.Descending
        SortTrackingGrid(e.SortExpression, " Desc")
    Else
        ViewState("SortDirection") = SortDirection.Ascending
        SortTrackingGrid(e.SortExpression, " Asc")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub SortTrackingGrid(ByVal SortExpression As String, ByVal SortDirection As String)

    Dim TrackingDt As New DataTable

    TrackingDt = objWebService.BindPWork()

    Dim Trackingdv As New DataView
    Trackingdv = TrackingDt.DefaultView

    'Sort the grid
    Trackingdv.Sort = SortExpression + SortDirection
    grdPWork.DataSource = Trackingdv
    grdPWork.DataBind()


End Sub
```

Comment: can you show the aspx page gridview markup?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete example of Sorting a grid view with autogenerate column false.

http://www.dotnetgallery.com/kb/resource12-How-to-implement-paging-and-sorting-in-aspnet-Gridview-control.aspx

Basically you need to use SortExpression in GridView Sorting event.

```
protected void Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] SortOrder = ViewState["SortExpr"].ToString().Split(' ');
        if (SortOrder[0] == e.SortExpression)
        {
            if (SortOrder[1] == "ASC")
            {
                ViewState["SortExpr"] = e.SortExpression + " " + "DESC";
            }
            else
            {
                ViewState["SortExpr"] = e.SortExpression + " " + "ASC";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ViewState["SortExpr"] = e.SortExpression + " " + "ASC";
        }
        GridVwPagingSorting.DataSource = Getdata();
        GridVwPagingSorting.DataBind();
    }
```